# Question regarding two letters of the alphabet selected at random, one after the other. Find $\mathbb{E}(x)$.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Two letters of the alphabet selected at random, one after the other. If both letters are the same, you win $20$ dollars. Otherwise, you lose $1$ dollar. There is replacement. Let $x =$ the amount won when the game is one at a time. Find $E(x)$.

Attempt:

$$\mathbb{E}(x)= x_1P(x_1)+x_2P(x_2)+…+x_nP(x_n)$$

$x_1=20$

$x_2=-1$

The probability of drawing the same letter twice: $P(x_1)=\frac{1}{26}\times\frac{1}{26}= \frac{1}{676}$

The probability of drawing two different letters: $P(x_2)= 1-\frac{1}{26}=\frac{25}{26}$

Thus

$\mathbb{E}(x) = 20\times\frac{1}{676}+(-1)\times\frac{25}{26} = -0.93$

Am I right?

Comment: this is not clear.  Since there is replacement, the game can go on forever.  What makes it stop?  And what does $x_n$ mean?

Comment: hint: the sum of the probabilities of each outcome needs to add to 1.

Comment: **If** I am interpreting the question correctly, the probability of failure is $~\displaystyle \left[ ~\frac{25}{26} ~\right]. ~$  Note that the probability of succeeding (or failing) is **independent** of which letter is the first letter drawn.

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe it's asking for the expected value $x_1P(x_1)+x_2P(x_2)$

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is asking "What is the expected value of net gain/loss when someone chooses two cards with replacement from the deck (with the given conditions of gain and loss)". In this case your calculation is correct.

But if you say "This is a game and it stops when the player draws two same cards" and your question is " what is the expected net gain/loss in this game", then finding the expected value requires an infinite sum and the calculation gets difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Posting, as another answer (wrong according to me) has been posted. I take it that you lose your stake of $1\$$ which is not returned when you play a game, and either you lose it or get $20\$$ as prize

Then P[Both same] $= 1*\frac{1}{26} = \frac1{26}$
and P[the two are different] $= 1 - \frac1{26} = \frac{25}{26}$

Thus in  one game of two draws with replacement.

Net winnings $\mathbb E[X] = 20*\frac1{26} - \frac{25}{26 }= \frac{19}{26}, \approx 0.73\,\$$

And if you play $n$ independent games, $\mathbb E[Y] = 0.73n\,\$$

If you find a foolish bookie offering such a game, go on and play to your heart's content !

Your mistake was computing P[Both same] as $\frac1{26}\frac{1}{26}$, because the first result can be **anything**, only the second result has to match the first.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on P[Both the same]! So what you're saying is that the first result is just $\frac{26}{26}$ because you can choose anything and the second result is  $\frac{1}{26}$ because there is a 1 in 26 chance of choosing the desired outcome.

Comment: Yes, that is correct !